# passing overloaded function pointer as argument to overloaded template function

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to get the compiler to deduce the correct function template.
Given the following code, the correct templated function is deduced...

```
class TestBase{};

template <typename c, typename RT, typename T0>
inline void CallF( RT( c::*M )(T0), TestBase* pObject, std::vector<OVariant> args )
{
    //safely convert variant (implementations external to class)
    T0 t0 = args[0].GetSafe<T0>();

    ((static_cast<c*>(pObject))->*M)(t0);
}

template <typename c, typename RT, typename T0, typename T1>
inline void CallF( RT( c::*M )(T0, T1), TestBase* pObject, std::vector<OVariant> args )
{
    //safely convert variant (implementations external to class)
    T0 t0 = args[0].GetSafe<T0>();
    T1 t1 = args[1].GetSafe<T1>();

    ((static_cast<c*>(pObject))->*M)(t0, t1);
}

class Test : public TestBase
{
public:

    void F( s32 one )
    {
        std::cout << "one";
    }

    struct Wrapped_F
    {
        //OVariant is my typical variant class
        static void Call( TestBase* pObject, std::vector<OVariant> args )
        {
            ::CallF<Test>( &Test::F, pObject, args );
        }
    };
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Test t;
    OVariant i( 13 );
    std::vector<OVariant> args;
    args.push_back( i );

    t.Wrapped_F::Call( &t, args );
}
```

t.Wrapped_F::Call( &t, args ) calls the correct F function.  However, if I add the overloaded F function to Test, then it (overload with 2 args) will be called (instead of the correct F with 1 arg)

```
void F( s32 one, s32 two )
{
    std::cout << "two";
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is due to the fact that the compiler does not have enough info to deduce.  How can I help the compiler deduce which overloaded template function to call?

Something like the following pseudo code... (? to denote some arg of unknown type)

```
static void Call( TestBase* pObject, std::vector<OVariant> args )
{
    //Note: I won't know anything about the arguments to function F; I do know the size of the vector
    switch ( args.size() )
    {
    case 1:::CallF<Test,void,?>( &Test::F, pObject, args );
    case 2:::CallF<Test,void,?,?>( &Test::F, pObject, args );
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has no way of knowing what is stored inside your variant class. So the `?` could be deduced *only* from the function type (from its parameters). Hence, you will need some code to check that `args.size()` matches the number of function parameter. Try to do the following:

- Create `std::tuple<Args...>` where `Args...` are evaluated from the function type
- Check that `args.size()` is the same as number of elements in the  `std::tuple<Args...>`
- Convert your `args` vector to the tuple.
- Use `std::apply` (or re-invent your own) to call your function with arguments from the tuple

Comment: I tried variations of your idea, but it doesn't seem to fit quite right.  How would creating std::tuple<Args...> work if the function type is not known in the Call function?  Would I lose the ability to call OVariant::GetSafe (T0 t0 = args[0].GetSafe<T0>();)